# Delete multiple lines in MySQL from a string

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, sql-delete

I know this has been asked a few times, but I've looked through quite a few SO posts and could not find anything to help me out.

I have a javascript function that will add values to an element to appear as such:

```
value="1,3,5,16"
```

However the values could be completely different depending on what the user chooses. This value is then sent to a php file to perform a MySQL DELETE function from the database.

Each value is actually an ID number of a record in the database that will need to be deleted.

I cannot get the MySQL statement to recognize multiple ID numbers. It only recognizes one (the first).

HTML:

```
<form method='post' action='delete_ids.php'>
   <input type='hidden' value="1,2,4,8,12,16" id='myvalues' name='myvalues'/>
   <button type='submit' id='submitBtn'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

   require("config.php");  // THIS IS MY DATABASE CONNECTION
   $x = $_POST['myvalues'];

   $result = "DELETE FROM `image_upload2` WHERE id IN ('$x')";
   $statement = $db->prepare($result);
   $count = $statement->execute();

?>
```

It works just fine if there is just ONE value, but when there are multiple values (commas in between) it will only delete the first record and not the rest. In the example above, only 'id' = 1 will be deleted.

Comment: Since it is a list of ids, you certainly don't need the single quotes around `$x`, though my guess would be that in your example no row at all would be deleted, since none of them has the id `'1,2,4,8,12,16'`.

Comment: PS: be aware that someone can post a different value that possibly puts your database in danger (SQL injection).

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy havig your server pwn3d.

Comment: Using `$x = (int)$_POST['myvalues'];` may help yet using [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) will help. Also checking with [`is_numeric()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) is another usable option.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks. Good to know. But this will be an admin controlled area and if the admin wants to ruin his database thats his fault. And if someone hacks into the admin area then sql injecting a table will be the last of worries.

Comment: **Never** trust user input, even if it is being used internally. Remember, even your best friend could stab you in the back ;-)

Comment: The user is not inputting values. Javascript is pulling id tags from elements. Thank you for your concerns though. I know its not the best way to do things but as of now I have no idea how to prevent SQL Injection with what I have

Comment: Ah ok; just checking. ;-) and you're welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The single quotes around `$x` turn that into a string literal (in the context of the SQL statement sent to the database).  For example, consider:

```
DELETE FROM foo WHERE bar IN ('fee,fi,fo,fum');
```

The database doesn't care about all those commas within the string literal; the database sees that as a single string, one element inside the parens. Those comma characters are just part of the string.

I think what you want is for the comma to be interpreted as part of the SQL syntax. You likely want a query of the form:

```
DELETE FROM `image_upload2` WHERE id IN (1,2,4,8,12,16);
```

--or--

```
DELETE FROM `image_upload2` WHERE id IN ('1','2','4','8','12','16');
```

In those examples, the comma characters is seen as part of the SQL syntax, separating the literals.

---

(And I make just a brief mention here that your current code is vulnerable to SQL Injection, but that's an answer to different question.)

[XKCD Exploits of a Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0):

Its because your ID is inside the ' characters. You have to have the IDs one after another.

.. WHERE id IN ('1', '2', '3', ...);

Or just remove the ' character.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you want your sql statement to look like this:
    DELETE FROM 'image_upload2' 
    WHERE id in ('1','2','4','8','12','16')

But yours is coming out like this:
    DELETE FROM 'image_upload2' 
    WHERE id in ('1,2,4,8,12,16')

So your sql query thinks that your list is a single element. Either add the quotes when you retrieve the value from the POST, or when you add items to the value of the input.

Answer (score 0):

Not a PHP expert myself, but it looks like the single quotes in your SQL string are the problem. It looks like it would become:

```
DELETE FROM `image_upload2` WHERE id IN ('1,2,4,8,12,16')
```

When it should be:

```
DELETE FROM `image_upload2` WHERE id IN (1,2,4,8,12,16)
```